# How to configure Cyber-ark to automatically update password for DCOM application

Tags: excel, dcom, cyber-ark

I have an account that is used on a server to run Scheduled Tasks.  I have this account set up in a Cyber-Ark password vault.  I have set-up Cyber-Ark to automatically update the Scheduled Task with an updated password whenever the account's password is changed.

Now, I also have manually set the DCOM config for "Microsoft Excel Application" to use the same username and have manually set the password.

I would like to have this also automatically update when the account's password is changed, but I am unsure how to do so.  I have added "Microsoft Excel Application" with the server's name as the address in the COM+ Application tab for the account within Cyberark.

The error I receive is

> The Central Policy Manager failed to change the password.
>   Error while trying to connect to ComPlus catalog on serverName.fmi.com with user app-adc-cyberark-rec in domain fmi.com. Native error message: The component or application containing the component has been disabled

I receive this same error when I change the name to something that definitely does not exist on the server (Micron Excel Application), so I believe I am leaving out a key piece of configuration rather than a setting on the server being the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to link the account with the server name. Need to associate the task with the account which can change the password

Comment: Thanks.    I have since moved on to other opportunities and am no longer working with Cyber-Ark.